# How can I compute the $n$-th complete Bell polynomial?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, summation, polynomials, recursion

I'm interested in computing the n-th [complete Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Exponential_Bell_polynomials)
$
B_n(x_1,..., x_n)
$ using the formula given as the last equation in the "Exponential Bell polynomials" section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Exponential_Bell_polynomials) (I tried posting the equation here but the math code would keep getting marked as an "error" in formatting, apologies), which is written as a sum in terms of the incomplete Bell polynomial $B_{n,k}(x_1, ..., x_{n-k+1})$.

Looking at the Mathematica [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BellY.html), I found that the incomplete Bell polynomial $B_{n,k}$ is implemented as

```
BellY[n,k,{x₁,…,xₙ₋ₖ₊₁}]
```

So I was thinking that I could compute the complete Bell polynomial using the equation from the article. The problem is that each summand has a different number of inputs, and I don't know how to implement a sum with this condition. Moreover, I would ideally like the polynomials to be outputted with variables (not evaluated at any specific values), and I also don't know how to do this.

Any and all ideas or suggestions are very much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]

bell[0] := 1

bell[n_Integer?Positive, var_Symbol : x] :=
 Sum[BellY[n, k, Array[var, n - k + 1]], {k, 1, n}]

Column[bell /@ Range[0, 7], Frame -> All] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Example:

```
bell[4] /. Thread[Array[x, 4] -> {1, 7, 5, 3}]

(* 213 *)
```

or

```
Evaluate[Array[y, 4]] = {1, 7, 5, 3};

bell[4, y]

(* 213 *)
```

**EDIT:** To also accept a list as an argument, extend the definition of `bell` with

```
bell[{}] = 1;

bell[lst_List] := Module[{n = Length@lst},
  Sum[BellY[n, k, lst[[;; n - k + 1]]], {k, 1, n}]]
```

Comparing with the original form

```
bell[Array[x, #]] === bell[#] & /@ Range[7]

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)

bell[{1, 7, 5, 3}]

(* 213 *)
```